# Chronological order of How to Train Your Dragon short films?

Tags: chronology, how-to-train-your-dragon, legend-of-the-boneknapper, gift-of-the-night-fury

Which comes first in chronological order, Gift of the Night Fury or Legend of the Boneknapper Dragon in  How to Train Your Dragon  franchise?

Comment: I hope I got you intent with my edit, let me know if I did anything wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The Order of the videos are

1. How to train your dragon (movie)
2. Riders of Berk (TV Series)
3. Defenders of Berk (TV Series)
4. *
5. Race to the Edge (TV Series)
6. How to train your dragon 2 (Movie)

I intentionally left 4 because the short films can be watched in any order before Race to the Edge, because by Race to the Edge all the necessary plot is fixed for the story line of the second movie. I suggest you watch short films in the order they were released.